# Am I able to get fall recipes in bottles?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I've been trying to collect the fall recipes, namely the maple leaf and the mushroom set, but I have no success thus far from bottles washed up in the beach... so, is it possible to obtain said seasonal recipes from bottles, or am I wasting my time and am suppose to look out for balloons and/or from villagers instead?

Answer (score 3):

No, the seasonal recipes will only come from balloons.